# Errors on IntelliJ android.app does not exist

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Im getting this errors:

```
 Error(3, 19) package android.app does not exist

    Error(4, 18) package android.os does not exist

    Error(6, 33) cannot find symbol
    symbol: class Activity

    Error(11, 26)cannot find symbol
    symbol: class Bundle

    Error(12, 9)cannot find symbol
    symbol  : variable super

    Error(13, 9)cannot find symbol
    symbol  : method setContentView(int)

    Error(10, 5)method does not override or implement a method from a supertype.
```

I know which I has to install the library, but Im confused about this.

How should I do this? Im using osx

Thanks a lot.